# Unity как вращать объект по оси Z чтоб он не двигался с места

Tags: c#, unity3d, 3d

Объект двигается по оси, но при этом не в на месте. Как это исправить.
На видео как должно быть и как происходит у меня.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RRNbox3D19Oib8Tm5dGiI0hQ8iFjKWJS/view?usp=sharing

Код:

```
public class CamerSwitch : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject rotateGamObj;
    public float rotSpeed = 10;
    public float offset = 0;
    void Start()
    {
        
    }


    void OnMouseDrag() {
        float rotX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")*rotSpeed*Mathf.Deg2Rad;

        rotateGamObj.transform.RotateAround(Vector3.down, rotX + offset);

    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Так он и вращается на месте, а не вокруг центра баунда как в редакторе, где можно увидеть как он меняет координату.

Answer (score 0):

Как варианты:

1. Переместить Pivot Родительского объекта "Banka" (Pivot префаба) в центр объекта.
2. Написать код, который будет в нужный момент двигать объект.

По-другому никак.